# PhantomJS webpage#render doesn't show javascript generated SVG which is included in webpage#content

Tags: javascript, pdf, svg, phantomjs

This is my PhantomJS script: https://gist.github.com/beckyconning/5404506

This is the javascript included in the page: https://gist.github.com/beckyconning/5404532

This is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="participant-overview-chart"></div>
```

The chart is displayed in all browsers and the svg is included in the output of webpage#content however it does not display in the file that PhantomJS's webpage#render creates.

If I include the generated SVG manually into the div it is displayed, but I need to generate these graphics automatically.

I've tried injecting jQuery and running $(document).ready and there is a timeout included in my current PhantomJS script. I don't know what to try next lol!

Thanks for any help or pointers on debugging this : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PhantomJS jQuery returns an inaccurate value from $().height();

Manually setting the Raphael drawing context width and height rather than taking this from the height in pixels of the element solved the problem.

```
var chart_container = $('#participant-overview-chart');
var chart_width = 529; //chart_container.height();
var chart_height = 529; //chart_container.height();
var r = Raphael(chart_container[0], 529, 529);
```

Gonna try using the non plain javascript way of getting pixel dimensions from an element and I'll update this if that works.

Protip for debugging PhantomJS PDF missing element errors: Render the webpage as a PNG. This lets shows the document against a transparent background which can help you find where the element is hiding.